# How to add some calculation in columns of the dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Input excel sheet]

I am having the excel sheet using the pandas.read_excel, I got the output in dataframe but I want to add the calculations in the after reading through pandas I need to ado following calculation in each x and y columns.

```
ratiox = (73.77481944859028 - 73.7709567323327) / 720
ratioy = (18.567453940477293 - 18.56167674097576) / 1184
mapLongitudeStart = 73.7709567323327
mapLatitudeStart = 18.567453940477293
longitude = 0, latitude = 0
longitude = (mapLongitudeStart + x1 * ratiox))  #I have take for the single column x1 value
latitude = (mapLatitudeStart - (-y1 *ratioy ))   # taken column y1 value
```

how to apply this calculation to every column and row of x and y a which has the values it should not take the null values. And I want the new dataframe created by doing the calculation in columns

Comment: Could you please provide some example-rows from the `pandas Dataframe` in text-form?

Comment: Pune पुणे हवेली बाणेर 3 ROAD WHITE #FFFFFF 11803.84 -3546.78 11808.36 -3531.79 11812.89 -3523.84 11830.37 -3523.84 11854.1 -3545.22 11854.1 -3548.58 11890.25 -3566.37 11942.91 -3577.78 11970.66 -3587.68 12005.36 -3587.68 12018.9 -3582.07 12033.11 -3582.07 12074.74 -3569.53 12066.81 -3603.85 12050.64 -3689.78 12046.44 -3712.12 12038.74 -3725.88 12034.46 -3769.25 12027.85 -3791.69 12005.81 -3791.68 12045.49 -3625.73 12039.1 -3609.91 12009.37 -3621.93 11971.88 -3621.93 11942.31 -3608.22 11888.45 -3596.61 11850.94 -3583.88

Comment: Above is the single row data in text form

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include data, not add it in a comment

Comment: You should add the column headers too and probably you can explain the issue using less columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
df = pd.read_excel('file_path')
dfx=df.ix[:,'x1'::2]
dfy=df.ix[:,'y1'::2]
li=[dfx.apply(lambda x:mapLongitudeStart + x * ratiox),dfy.apply(lambda y:mapLatitudeStart - (-y))]
df_new=pd.concat(li,axis=1)
df_new = df_new[list(itertools.chain(*zip(dfx.columns,dfy.columns)))]
print(df_new)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want the columns should be x and y format means  columns such as  x1 ,y1,x2,y2 and so on .Can you please suggest for this

Comment: @P.D Please check the edited answer. It should work!

Comment: I am getting this error [ NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined ] I have also imported  from itertools import chain

Comment: When I am using only {import itertools} error doesn't come but the output is getting in the previous ways not in x and y columns form

Comment: Printing df_new would give you the x and y columns wise form. Please check!

Comment: check now! I have reassigned the df_new value.

Comment: Can you please suggest the issue posted at 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135246/how-to-convert-the-row-wise-data-of-dataframe-with-its-column-name-as-key-and-ro?noredirect=1#comment102657657_58135246

Comment: sure! will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend to reshape your data into a long format, that way you can get rid of the empty cells naturally. Also most pandas functions work better that way, because then you can use things like group by operations on all x or y or wahtever dimenstion

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

## this part is only to have a running example 
## here you would load your excel file
D = pd.DataFrame( 
        np.random.randn(10,6), 
        columns =chain(*[ [f"x{i}", f"y{i}"]  for i in range(1,4)])
    ) 

D["rowid"] = pd.np.arange(len(D))
D = D.melt(id_vars="rowid").dropna()
D["varIndex"] = D.variable.str[1]
D["variable"] = D.variable.str[0]

D = D.set_index(["varIndex","rowid","variable"])\
    .unstack("variable")\
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

So these transformations will give you a table where you have an index both for the original row id (maybe it is a time series or something else), and the variable index so x**1** or x**2** etc.

[image: table after long format]

Now you can do your calculations either by overwintering the previous columns

```
## Everything here is a constant
ratiox = (73.77481944859028 - 73.7709567323327) / 720
ratioy = (18.567453940477293 - 18.56167674097576) / 1184
mapLongitudeStart = 73.7709567323327
mapLatitudeStart = 18.567453940477293

# apply the calculations directly to the columns
D.x = (mapLongitudeStart + D.x * ratiox))
D.y = (mapLatitudeStart - (-D.y * ratioy ))
```

Comment: I want to add this calculation in every x and y column