# How to convert the row-wise data of dataframe with its column name as key and row data as value in json using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

[image: Input dataframe df is attached]

I am having the issue in converting the row-wise data of dataframe with the column name as key and row data as value. I want to pass this row-wise json to another API as an input. I am unable to get this json data.

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    out =row.to_json(orient='records',force_ascii=False)[1:-1].replace('},{', '} {')
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=out.encode('utf-8'))
    print(r.json())
```

I want the desired output of the json in the attached format 
[image: Desired output of the json]

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question with the images of the input and desired json output. Please check and kindly suggest

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you create sample data in text with 1, 2 points and 3 rows?

Comment: As I am new to this, so posted the image.

Comment: No problem, check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I already referred this link but can't get the desired output in the json from the dataframe

Comment: Can you please suggest for the issue

Comment: @P.D Please post your sample data using Dataframe instead of posting data images. And also upvote any answer below if it helps in your case so that others would also get benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
def call_api(json_data):
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=out)
    print(r.json())

df.apply(lambda x:call_api(x.to_json()),axis=1)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this hope it will work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(your file path)
df.to_json()
```

Comment: It will convert the complete dataframe into the json. I want to take rowwise json data to provide the rowwise json as an input to other post API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your target data format is [newline-delimited JSON](http://jsonlines.org/). In `pandas` you can convert your dataframe to newline-delimited JSON file using `to_json()` method of dataframe with setting `lines` parameter to `True`:

Data preparation part:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data_json = [
    {
        'C_ID' : '1',
        'Latlong' : {
            '__type' : 'GeoPoint',
            'latitude' : [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        }
    },
    {
        'C_ID' : '2',
        'Latlong' : {
            '__type' : 'GeoPoint',
            'latitude' : [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        }
    },
    {
        'C_ID' : '3',
        'Latlong' : {
            '__type' : 'GeoPoint',
            'latitude' : [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        }
    }]

data = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_json))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   C_ID                                            Latlong
0     1  {'__type': 'GeoPoint', 'latitude': [[1, 2], [3...
1     2  {'__type': 'GeoPoint', 'latitude': [[1, 2], [3...
2     3  {'__type': 'GeoPoint', 'latitude': [[1, 2], [3...
```

Writing dataframe to json file in newline-delimited format:

```
data.to_json(path_or_buf='/path/to/target/json/file.json', # path to json file to write data
             orient='records',
             lines=True)
```

Output file data:

```
{"C_ID":1,"Latlong":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]}}
{"C_ID":2,"Latlong":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]}}
{"C_ID":3,"Latlong":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]}}
```